# Why does Sleep(500) cost more than 500ms?

Tags: c++, winapi, sleep

I used `Sleep(500)` in my code and I used `getTickCount()` to test the timing. I found that it has a cost of about 515ms, more than 500. Does somebody know why that is?

Comment: getTickCount has a granularity of about 10-16 ms.

Comment: `Sleep(n)` does not guarantee that you sleep for exactly `n`ms, just that you sleep for _at least_ `n`ms.

Comment: The question is still relevant without the winapi tag.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg: I'm surprised, that your comment got so many votes for being useful, when it isn't even true. The documentation of [Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298.aspx) does not back your claim. Specifically: *"If dwMilliseconds is less than the resolution of the system clock, the thread may sleep for less than the specified length of time."* and *"If dwMilliseconds is greater than one tick but less than two, the wait can be **anywhere** between one and two ticks, and so on"* (emphasis mine).

Comment: I have a laptop that regularly returns from `Sleep` calls at about half the time requested, so those answers reporting "`Sleep` guarantees at least `dwMilliseconds` sleep", I'm not even agreeing with that. I think it is related to [Intel's SpeedStep](http://superuser.com/q/183508/39835) but I'm not sure enough to mention this in an answer.

Comment: @MarkHurd: Unless you are talking about very short durations (in the range of the system clock) it sounds more like you have buggy chipset drivers. The documentation does guarantee that `Sleep` will return no sooner than the requested time minus one system clock tick (or 0, whichever is larger).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Because Win32 API's `Sleep` isn't a high-precision sleep, and has a maximum granularity.

The best way to get a precision sleep is to sleep a bit less (~50 ms) and do a busy-wait. To find the exact amount of time you need to busywait, get the resolution of the system clock using `timeGetDevCaps` and multiply by 1.5 or 2 to be safe.

Comment: As we say around these parts, "one person's realtime system is another person's batch system".  It's all about how tolerable the latency can be, along with the variability of that latency.  Realtime behavior is usually a very critical design decision, not just from a software API standpoint, but what I/O is there, what it's hooked up to (or not hooked up to, think timeouts), and how it affects the "realtime" latency.  Blocked calls vs. asynchronous calls, etc.

Comment: @franji1 There's another use to sleep I did not mention in my answer, which is very relevant for one type of application: games. The default in games is to busywait until the next frame. This is incredibly power and CPU hungry. Simply doing a sleep if the time until next frame is larger than a system tick away and busywaiting the rest has brought down CPU usage from 100% to less than 5% on some games.

Comment: In the good old Amstrad and Spectrum game-writing days, you could use a firmware interrupt with extreme reliability and negligible cpu burn. We could even change the graphics "mode" a certain way down the scren. Sadly I've moved away from this field now, but can't you do something similar?

Comment: @Bathsheba I'm sure there's always more options when targeting specific hardware - the code I've written for games has always been at the OS level, and cross-platform (generally one implementation for linux and another for Windows).

Comment: Games usually do not render at fixed time intervals. Instead, they render as fast as possible, and base the scene information on the current timestamp. Games don't use `Sleep`.

Comment: @IInspectable Nearly every game has an option to lock at 60 or 120 FPS. A proper implementation of those locks sleep. Common vsync implementation block, and thus sleep. New gsync/freesync also blocks, and thus implicitly sleep.

Comment: Games that have an option to synchronize with the display's refresh rate do so by using the hardware's capabilities to wait for the *vertical blank*. They do not use `Sleep`.

Comment: While `beginTimePeriod` has its downsides, I'd prefer it over a busy-wait in most scenarios.

Comment: @CodesInChaos If precision is required a busywait is unavoidable. My answer suggests a combination of busywaiting and sleeping.

Comment: Do not forget that at those small resolutions, you may not even be getting a timeslot from the os scheduler at the time you need it.

Comment: @Bathsheba This only started to be a problem when power management became an issue - in the olden days, the CPU was running at 100% all the time anyway. Modern OSes have support for event-based timers, which allow you a more granular control over timer events - however, for backwards compatibility, the old quantum-based timers are still supported, and used in functions like `Thread.Sleep`. And of course, if you don't need more update cycles than you have GPU refreshes, you can use vsync to block until the frame is rendered to screen.

Comment: The OS environment on "Amstrad and Spectrum" allowed you access to such features because it could afford to, since reliable multitasking operation was not expected of these systems. If you could directly hook into that kind of timer interrupt on a modern OS, you could effectively *preempt the operating system* ... and crash it very easily by accident or malice. You still have timers like that in an RTOS environment, or in small microcontroller environments (like MCS51) that can reasonably be used without an OS.

Comment: The same is true of `sleep` functions in basically every programming language. You wait at least x milliseconds and then wait for your process to be scheduled by the kernel

Comment: Notice that even if you sleep for slightly less than the desired time and then busywait, you will still occasionally end up sleeping significantly longer than desired. This happens whenever the sleeping thread is preempted in-between starting the busywait and getting to the next command, which generally happens nondeterministically and depends on what else is going on in the system at the time.

Comment: Busy waiting does not give hard guarantees either. Another process can be scheduled in the middle of your loop.

Answer (score 30):

`sleep(500)` guarantees a sleep of *at least* 500ms.

But it might sleep for longer than that: the upper limit is not defined.

In your case, there will also be the extra overhead in calling `getTickCount()`.

Your non-standard `Sleep` function may well behave in a different matter; but I doubt that exactness is guaranteed. To do that, you need special hardware.

Comment: MSDN explicitly mentions an accuracy up to the system clock ticks and makes no mention of an undefined upper limit.

Comment: So what? The platform might not be relevant to MSDN.

Comment: The `Sleep` function is not a C++ standard function, it's Win32 API specific, just like `GetTickCount`.

Comment: That might be the case, but the OP tags the question with the lower case `sleep`. Of course that might be in error, but I believe my answer has credibility. In reality, you can't really perform an accurate pause without extra hardware.

Comment: Tags can not contain uppercase letters, a moot point. Plus, the combination of `Sleep` and `GetTickCount` occurs to my knowledge only in Win32 API.

Comment: @orlp the indefinite upper limit comes about because there's no promise that your process will be scheduled immediately after its allotted sleep completes. A higher-priority task might hold the CPU for any length of time before you run again. There's also no promise that a meteor won't hit the computer before your sleep completes :)

Comment: The MSDN documentation for [Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298.aspx) doesn't specify an upper limit. But you got the lower limit wrong as well, so your answer really has very limited value.

Answer (score 18):

As you can read in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the WinAPI function `GetTickCount()`

> is limited to the resolution of the system timer, which is typically in the range of 10 milliseconds to 16 milliseconds.

To get a more accurate time measurement, use the function  [`GetSystemDatePreciseAsFileTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Also, you can not rely on `Sleep(500)` to sleep *exactly* 500 milliseconds. It will suspend the thread for *at least* 500 milliseconds. The operating system will then continue the thread as soon as it has a timeslot available. When there are many other tasks running on the operating system, there might be a delay.

Answer (score 13):

In general sleeping means that your thread goes to a waiting state and after 500ms it will be in a "runnable" state. Then the OS scheduler chooses to run *something* according to the priority and number of runnable processes at that time. So if you do have high precision sleep and high precision clock then it is still a sleep for at least 500ms, not exactly 500ms.

Comment: +1 For mentioning the scheduler and the real reason why it will sleep for *at least* the requested time.

Comment: @JordanMelo: Except, that [Sleep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298.aspx) **doesn't** sleep *"for at least the requested time"*.

Comment: @IInspectable: Sorry, I didn't mean in general. But you're right: due to granularity of the system clock, the thread may sleep for slightly less than the requested time. My point is that you can't really rely on an accurate sleep time, even with a more granular clock.

Comment: @JordanMelo: Granularity has nothing to do with it. You can implement the guarantee to sleep *at least* the requested time, regardless of granularity. `Sleep` **decided** not to, and this contract is documented. You are right, still, that you cannot rely on a contract that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 12):

Like the other answers have noted, `Sleep()` has limited accuracy.  Actually, *no* implementation of a `Sleep()`-like function can be perfectly accurate, for several reasons:

- It takes some time to actually call `Sleep()`.  While an implementation aiming for maximal accuracy *could* attempt to measure and compensate for this overhead, few bother.  (And, in any case, the overhead can vary due to many causes, including CPU and memory use.)
- Even if the underlying timer used by `Sleep()` fires at *exactly* the desired time, there's no guarantee that your process will actually be rescheduled immediately after waking up.  Your process might have been swapped out while it was sleeping, or other processes might be hogging the CPU.
- It's possible that the OS *cannot* wake your process up at the requested time, e.g. because the computer is in suspend mode.  In such a case, it's quite possible that your 500ms `Sleep()` call will actually end up taking several hours or days.

Also, even if `Sleep()` was perfectly accurate, the code you want to run *after* sleeping will inevitably consume some extra time.
Thus, to perform some action (e.g. redrawing the screen, or updating game logic) at regular intervals, the standard solution is to use a *compensated* `Sleep()` loop.  That is, you maintain a regularly incrementing time counter indicating when the next action *should* occur, and compare this target time with the current system time to dynamically adjust your sleep time.

Some extra care needs to be taken to deal with unexpected large time jumps, e.g. if the computer was temporarily suspected or if the tick counter wrapped around, as well as the situation where processing the action ends up taking more time than is available before the next action, causing the loop to lag behind.

Here's a quick example implementation (in pseudocode) that should handle both of these issues:

```
int interval = 500, giveUpThreshold = 10*interval;
int nextTarget = GetTickCount();

bool active = doAction();
while (active) {
    nextTarget += interval;
    int delta = nextTarget - GetTickCount();
    if (delta > giveUpThreshold || delta < -giveUpThreshold) {
        // either we're hopelessly behind schedule, or something
        // weird happened; either way, give up and reset the target
        nextTarget = GetTickCount();
    } else if (delta > 0) {
        Sleep(delta);
    }
    active = doAction();
}
```

This will ensure that `doAction()` will be called *on average* once every `interval` milliseconds, at least as long as it doesn't consistently consume more time than that, and as long as no large time jumps occur.  The exact time between successive calls may vary, but any such variation will be compensated for on the next interation.

Answer (score 2):

Default timer resolution is low, you could increase time resolution if necessary. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
#define TARGET_RESOLUTION 1         // 1-millisecond target resolution

TIMECAPS tc;
UINT     wTimerRes;

if (timeGetDevCaps(&tc, sizeof(TIMECAPS)) != TIMERR_NOERROR) 
{
    // Error; application can't continue.
}

wTimerRes = min(max(tc.wPeriodMin, TARGET_RESOLUTION), tc.wPeriodMax);
timeBeginPeriod(wTimerRes);
```

Comment: This may not be accurate enough compared to busywaiting and I wouldn't mess with the system clock. Other processes might get messed up, and according to MSDN: _"Use caution when calling timeBeginPeriod, as frequent calls can significantly affect the system clock, system power usage, and the scheduler."_.

Comment: My previous comment wasn't entirely accurate, `timeBeginPeriod` doesn't mess up other processes.

Comment: @orlp The advice doesn't really apply to having a foreground fullscreen media application running. It's targeted at offenders like, say, Chrome. Many applications change the quantum and keep it changed even when they don't really need the extra precision. In any case, this has finally been solved (in Win 7 or 8, I think) - the system timer no longer cares about the quantum, it's event-based. Yay :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two general reasons why code might want a function like "sleep":

1. It has some task which can be performed at any time that is at least some distance in the future.
2. It has some task which should be performed as near as possible to some moment in time some distance in the future.

In a good system, there should be separate ways of issuing those kinds of requests; Windows makes the first easier than the second.

Suppose there is one CPU and three threads in the system, all doing useful
work until, one second before midnight, one of the threads says it won't have
anything useful to do for at least a second.  At that point, the system will
devote execution to the remaining two threads.  If, 1ms before midnight,
one of those threads decides it won't have anything useful to do for at least
a second, the system will switch control to the last remaining thread.

When midnight rolls around, the original first thread will become available to
run, but since the presently-executing thread will have only had the CPU for
a millisecond at that point, there's no particular reason the original first
thread should be considered more "worthy" of CPU time than the other thread
which just got control.  Since switching threads isn't free, the OS may very
well decide that the thread that presently has the CPU should keep it until
it blocks on something or has used up a whole time slice.

It might be nice if there were a version of "sleep" which were easier to use
than multi-media timers but would request that the system give the thread a
temporary priority boost when it becomes eligible to run again, or better yet
a variation of "sleep" which would specify a minimum time and a "priority-
boost" time, for tasks which need to be performed within a certain time window.  I don't know of any systems that can be easily made to work that way, though.

Comment: Actually, I think Win32 `CreateWaitableTimer` works *exactly* the way you ask for -- easy to use and automatically gives a temporary (dynamic) priority boost.  See [MSDN "Priority Boosts" article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684828(v=vs.85).aspx): "When the wait conditions for a blocked thread are satisfied, the scheduler boosts the priority of the thread. For example, when a wait operation associated with disk or keyboard I/O finishes, the thread receives a priority boost."  The thread is more worthy of attention, because it's been patiently waiting.